# C won't finish reading the program after while loop

Tags: c

Everytime I try to press <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> the while loop it won't print out the average.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a;
    float b = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while(1){
        scanf("%f", &a);
        b += a;
        counter++;
    }

    float average = b/counter;
    printf("%f", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ctrl-z simply suspends a job, pausing it. It doesn't cause it to break out of a loop.

Comment: Stop getting a sunbath and get on with your homework, dude :)

Comment: Likely this is on Windows, where Ctrl+Z does pretty close to what Ctrl+D does in Linux. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z

Comment: CTRL-D and scanf(..) == 1 was the way to go thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Because there is no condition to `break` out (terminate) the loop, i.e, this is an infinite loop.

Try this instead:

```
while(1){
    if(scanf("%f", &a) == 1)
    {
        b += a;
        counter++;
    }
    else break;
    }
}
```

Now, pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> (as you mentioned in the question) will terminate the loop.

Comment: Perhaps this is on Windows, where Ctrl+Z does pretty close to what Ctrl+D does in Linux. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z

Comment: @FredLarson; I know. Read OP's question. He is talking about `Ctrl+Z`.

Comment: Yeah, I should have put a @unwind on that.

Comment: @FredLarson Ah, didn't see that in the OP. Still stray brace though.

Answer (score 4):

If you're in Linux and expect <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> to finish the input, you're mistaken. It's <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, but it's <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> in Windows though.

(What <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> does in Linux is generally (in Bash and other shells) to *suspend* the program, meaning it's temporarily stopped but still exists as a process.)

You should change your loop to something like:

```
while(scanf("%f", &a) == 1)
{
  b += a;
  ++counter;
}
```

and then try again with the EOF keyboard sequence (or just some non-numeric input).

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb:

**NEVER** use an endless loop without making sure you have a **hitable** `break` statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a;
    float b = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while(1){
        if(scanf("%f", &a) == 1)
        {
           b += a;
           counter++;
        }
        else break;
    }

    float average = b/counter;
    printf("%f", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of while(1), you need to test for eof().

Try `while(scant("%f", &a) == 1)`

see the man page for scant() and see what it says about return values, at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Your control Z is affecting the entire program, since it is inside the loop when you hit cntrl-Z the final section never executes.